# dual must be declared in oracle forms

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I am having problems for running an oracle form builder on my customer block.

It keeps saying

> "Identifier Dual must be declared"

here is my code

```
select cust_id_seq.nextval into :customer_block.cust_id from dual;
```

Comment: Can you somehow not see sys objects?  Try `sys.dual`.

Comment: Try running SELECT 1 FROM dual from SQLPLUS or SQL Developer using the same user from which your oracle form is getting executed and see if it is failing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are not connected to the database.
Connect and then compile and run the form.